# Android achartengine : filling below the line chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I found few questions on stackoverflow on this, but the answers there were :

```
    FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.ABOVE);
    fill.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

but when I use the above code snippet in my LineChart (no matter what the fill type is, excepting 'below' type), only the area *above* the line in the linechart gets filled as you can see below:

[image]

'BELOW' Type works partially. but the area below even the axes gets colored.

[image]

can someone please help?

Comment: It looks like you are using transparent background.

Comment: Yes @Dan ; you are right. Should I use a white (or color'ed) background & this issue will be fixed? Let me try that

Comment: @Dan, same behavior even if I change the background color to white. Is it possibly because the y-axis has negative values running from -100 to 0 ? If the AChartEngine trying to draw the color starting from 0 in the axis & that's why this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Tried it out. Yes, the issue seems to be because I have negative values on the Y Axis.

Works fine now with this hack:
Changed the Y Axis values to positive ones, but labeled the Y Axis with negative values. Used :

```
             FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ABOVE);
     fill.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
     renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```